# BoxDetection Algorithm

Tags: c#, crop, edge-detection

I am looking for guidance making a program in C# that take in a bunch of bmp images and detects a box on the image and returns the cropped box as a bmp image in a separate folder.

I am using Visual Basic 2010.

I have looked into all the different built in algorithms the .NET server has, and I have also downloaded and tried the Emgucv examples and what not. I found a program that uses a preset image and crops it to a certain rectangle specified by where the user clicks
http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=30725
and am trying to incorporate parts of this with the Example.ShapeDetection.exe that is built in to the Emgucv reference.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;

namespace Project1{
    public static class Project1 {
 public static void main()
    {
        //load in desired images to be processed
        //Load the image from file
     //for loop that runs all the code below for all the files in a certain folder
     //for example
     //for(int i = 0; i<"number of images in image folder"; i++){
     //code that loads the bmp images

    Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(fileNameTextBox.Text).Resize(400, 400, true);
    Image<Gray, Byte> gray = img.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();
    Gray cannyThreshold = new Gray(180);
    Gray cannyThresholdLinking = new Gray(120);
    Gray circleAccumulatorThreshold = new Gray(120);
    Image<Gray, Byte> cannyEdges = gray.Canny(cannyThreshold, cannyThresholdLinking);
    LineSegment2D[] lines = cannyEdges.HoughLinesBinary(
        1, //Distance resolution in pixel-related units
        Math.PI / 45.0, //Angle resolution measured in radians.
        20, //threshold
        10, //min Line width
        10 //gap between lines
        )[0]; //Get the lines from the first channel

    #region Find rectangles

    List<MCvBox2D> boxList = new List<MCvBox2D>();

    using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage()) //allocate storage for contour approximation
        for (Contour<Point> contours = cannyEdges.FindContours(); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
        {
            Contour<Point> currentContour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.05, storage);

            if (contours.Area > 100) //only consider contours with area greater than 250
            {
                if (currentContour.Total == 4) //The contour has 4 vertices.
                {
                    #region determine if all the angles in the contour are 90 degree's
                    bool isRectangle = true;
                    Point[] pts = currentContour.ToArray();
                    LineSegment2D[] edges = PointCollection.PolyLine(pts, true);

                    for (int i = 0; i < edges.Length; i++)
                    {
                        double angle = Math.Abs(
                           edges[(i + 1) % edges.Length].GetExteriorAngleDegree(edges[i]));
                        if (angle < 89 || angle > 91)
                        {
                            isRectangle = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion

                    if (isRectangle) boxList.Add(currentContour.GetMinAreaRect());
                }
            }
        }
    #endregion

    originalImageBox.Image = img;

    #region draw rectangles
    Image<Bgr, Byte> RectangleImage = img.Copy();
    foreach (MCvBox2D box in boxList)
        RectangleImage.Draw(box, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);
    RectangleImageBox.Image = RectangleImage;
    #endregion
}
}
}
```

This is the code I have at the moment and there are several problems with it that I know about but I can not seem to find a way to solve them.

1. filenameImageBox, originalImageBox, and RectangleImageBox do not exist in the current context. My guess is that this is because they referred to an image that no longer exists.
2. As it says in my comments, I am trying to write a loop that goes through all *.bmp images in Resources and loads them to the program. I'm not sure where to go on this though.
3. Most importantly though is that this code HOPEFULLY detects the rectangle I am looking for and simply re draws a rectangle in the same location with same dimensions on a blank image. What I would like it to do is to simply crop the rectangle to be the size of the full screen. There are parts in the Cropping Images program linked above that can do this but I was struggling isolating the cropping from that program with the rectangle detection of the ShapeDetection algorithm.

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have only been working in C# for a couple weeks, previous experience in c++ and Java though.

Answer (score 2):

here i guess this will help you

```
     else if (currentContour.Total == 4) //The contour has 4 vertices.
                    {double angle = Math.Abs(edges[(i + 1) % edges.Length].GetExteriorAngleDegree(edges[i]));
                             if (angle > 75 || angle < 95)
                            {...
```